# How to prevent my Flutter app from closing when pressing the home button or when minimized?

Tags: flutter, android-lifecycle

When ever I put my flutter app into the pause state, it instantly detached itself. How do I prevent this? I want to resume where I left off when I minimized my app.

[image: Console image]

Comment: not 100% sure what's your problem: is it, that the debug session closes when you minimize or close the app? Found that very annoying too. Try connection via wifi, it runs way more stable and easily reconnects when you reopen the app.

Comment: use this on how to connect: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#connect-to-a-device-over-wi-fi-android-11+

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.